# Failed to parse CASE statement. Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I'm getting an error when trying to add a [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement in Google Data Studio.

> Failed to parse Case Statement

Where am I going wrong?

```
CASE
  WHEN _count_featues_null value = 0 THEN COUNT_DISTINCT(dataset name )
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the [`COUNT_DISTINCT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583428) function (and checking the spelling of `_count_featues_null`?):

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE
    WHEN _count_featues_null value = 0 THEN dataset name
  END )
```